# copy the xib from one project to another project

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib, iboutlet

I need to copy xib files from one project to another project. This may be basic thing but I am new to xib file usage.

I manually copied the xxx.h, xxx.m & xxx.xib from project-1 and kept in one folder and included them in another project as "Right click on the Project-2 folder -> Add files to Project-2" option.

**(1)** I lost some IBOutlet connections after copying

**(2)** Xib not allowing to have new IBOutlet variables.

Then I copied the files from original location (Project-1 folder) but then

**(3)** If I create new IBOutlet connections the reference variable if I access I am getting nil value.

Could somebody help me the basics of how to move/copy the xib files and its sources.

Comment: Does class file of that xib from previous application already exist in your new application?

Comment: No.. I renamed the class name & xib name. Then lost the FileOwnership

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be two issues I sense in your copying.

1) While you are copying check option : "Copy selected items to destination folder". refer screenshot![image]

2) Also in your .xib file select File's owner --> Go to Identity Inspector in right top corner and select suitable class for that xib. When you add xib independently you have to set it's class manually like this.

[image]

Comment: Detailed answer with images +1

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thanks for detailed explanation. 2nd point was the issue. I am not aware of setting File's Owner. This image helped me a lot.

Comment: When you add xib independently you have to set it's class manually like this. You are not aware because till now you were checking option **"with xib for User Interface"** when adding new class.

Answer (score 2):

May be it will help you....
Click your .xib file and add the class name. Like this[image]

Comment: Remember you need to select File's Owner first. :)

Comment: @rohan-patel yes.. sorry I forgot... :)

Answer (score 1):

When copying you need to setup the class and outlet connections.

Follow these steps:

1. **Copy the xib**
2. **Add the class name of your xib in it's files owner**

[image: Class]

3. **Add the outlets**

[image: Outlets]

Comment: Beat me by 22 seconds.. =) +1 for you.